# Pass parameter from grid to javascript function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**GOAL**

What I am attempting to accomplish is from my GRIDMVC, upon clicking a button in my row, the ID of that row is passed to an onClick function to perform my computations.

**What I have so far** 
So far I have my grid with rows,Posted below is the code for the button

```
colums.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => @Html.ActionLink("Add Row", "Create", "Student", new { o.student_id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block", @onclick = "studentChecker('{o.student_id}');" }));
```

**Problem**

Problem is, through looking and trying various methods, I cannot seem to pass the student ID from the row INTO my studentChecker function correctly.

Any help or pointing to links which already discussed that would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `@onclick = "studentChecker('" + o.student_id + "');"`?

Comment: @ClaudiuGeorgiu ahh so it was the"+"  i needed, make an answer so I can selected please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the value of `o.student_id`, but if you write `"studentChecker('{o.student_id}');"` you are passing to the method the exact string `{o.student_id}`. In order to pass the actual value, write the name of the variable without quotes using string concatenation:

```
@onclick = "studentChecker('" + o.student_id + "');"
```